# Converting either an integer or a list of integers to a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert some data to a set, using the `set()` function. The data might either be a single integer, or a list of integers. While `set([list of integers])` works, it fails for `set(integer)`. Currently I check for the `type()` of the data and then either convert the list directly or create a set and add the single value.

As this seems quite complicated for achieving very little, I was wondering if there is an *easier / shorter / better* way to handle this?

Comment: `try: thing = set(stuff); except TypeError: thing = set((stuff,))`? Rather than explicitly checking the type, you just care whether you can make it into a `set` directly or need to wrap it in an iterable.

Comment: `set(int(i) for i in l)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj will have exactly the same problem when you try to iterate over `l = 1`: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: But `l = '1'` should work.

Comment: @AvinashRaj *"The data might either be a single integer, or a list of integers"*

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you should make that a proper answer. I'll add that it's better to avoid this situation by passing the single int in a list on it's own.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy it already is one!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I mean the maybe int maybe list variable is usually bad style. Just because Python lets you do it doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy no, I mean it's already an answer - I agree that a consistent return type is a good idea

Comment: Unfortunately the Python builtins give people ideas. For example `isinstance` takes "one or many types" as its second parameter.

Comment: Why do you have two forms of data? Can't you push that out?

Comment: @PeterWood: I probably can, I was just curious if one can convince `set()` to just take the single value and put it in a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python best practice says it's [*"Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp). So I would do:

```
value1 = 2
try:
  vset = set(value1)
except TypeError:
  vset = set([value1])
```